# Can I tell Retrofit to ignore OkHttp Dispatcher?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

I have a situation in an app, where there are a lot of network calls of the same endpoint (with different parameters) at the same time. This can cause other calls to be blocked.

The setup uses Retrofit + Kotlin Coroutines.

One solution I can think of is to run the calls with different instances of Retrofit+OkHttp using separate thread pools.

However, I'd prefer a single thread pool (and Retrofit instance) defining limitations via different kotlin coroutine dispatchers and the use of [limitedParallelism()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html).

See this code snippet:

```kotlin
class NetworkApi(
    private val retrofitWebserviceApi: RetrofitWebserviceApi,
    threadPoolExecutor: ThreadPoolExecutor,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = threadPoolExecutor.asCoroutineDispatcher()
        .limitedParallelism(CoroutineDispatcherConfig.ioDispatcherLimit),
    // A separate IO dispatcher pool so the many calls to getEntries don't block other calls
    private val noParallelismDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = dispatcher.limitedParallelism(1),
) {
    /**
     * Represents an endpoint, which needs to be called with a lot of different 
     * parameters at the same time (about 1000 times).
     * It's important these calls don't block the whole thread pool.
     */
    suspend fun getEntries(description: String) = withContext(noParallelismDispatcher) {
        retrofitWebserviceApi.getEntries(description)
    }

    /**
     * This call should not be blocked by [getEntries] calls, but be executed shortly after it is called.
     */
    suspend fun getCategories() = withContext(dispatcher) {
        retrofitWebserviceApi.getCategories()
    }
}
```

Full executable JVM code sample here: [github sample code - question branch](https://github.com/p-fischer/coroutines-retrofit-limitparallism/tree/question)

So the idea here is to limit parallel requests using Kotlin Coroutine Dispatchers.
However, the project logs show that OkHttp uses its own OkHttp Dispatcher.

Is there a way to de-activate the OkHttp Dispatcher and just run a network call in the current thread (defined by a Coroutine Dispatcher here)?

Is this possible without losing the possibility to cancel requests?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To use another dispatcher I think you need to remove `suspend` modifiers in `RetrofitWebserviceApi` for functions you want to use another dispatcher for:

```
internal interface RetrofitWebserviceApi {

    @GET("entries")
    fun getEntries(@Query("description") description: String): EntriesResponse

    @GET("categories")
    fun getCategories(): CategoriesResponse
}
```

Comment: I noticed it's also necessary to wrap the return type with `Call`.
Thanks for the pointer in the right direction @Sergio!

Answer (score 0):

Custom dispatcher can be set to OkhttpClient as below

```
  private fun createDispatcher(): Dispatcher {
    val dispatcher = Dispatcher(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
    dispatcher.maxRequests = 100
    dispatcher.maxRequestsPerHost = 100
    return dispatcher
  }

  private fun getOkHttpClient() = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(getLoggingInterceptor())
    .dispatcher(createDispatcher())
    .build()
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this option too. 
My goal here was to skip the OkHttp thread pool entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes, the OkHttp dispatcher is ignored if Retrofit calls are executed in a synchronuous way.

**Long answer:**

I went the same way [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731626/sergio) suggested.

Besides removing the `suspend` keyword it's necessary to wrap the result type with `Call`

```kotlin
internal interface RetrofitWebserviceApi {

    @GET("entries")
    fun getEntries(@Query("description") description: String): Call<EntriesResponse>

    @GET("categories")
    fun getCategories(
    ): Call<CategoriesResponse>
}
```

Defining a `Call<T>` return type is the canonical way to define Retrofit interfaces and provides 2 options:

1. Synchronuous exection calling `execute()` on the `Call` object. This returns `Response<T>`.
2. Asynchronous execution calling `enqueue()`. This provides `T` in the callback.

I needed to go with option 1.

Now, the OkHttp thread pool is ignored. The caller side is now responsible to dispatch the execution of the network call to a background thread.
That was my original intention.

The functions in `NetworkApi` now additionally need to call `execute()` and `body()` to obtain the result:

```kotlin
suspend fun getEntries(description: String) =
    retrofitWebserviceApi.getEntries(description)
        .executeWithDispatcher(noParallelismDispatcher)

suspend fun getCategories() =
    retrofitWebserviceApi.getCategories()
        .executeWithDispatcher(dispatcher)

private suspend fun <T> Call<T>.executeWithDispatcher(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher): T =
    withContext(dispatcher)
    {
        val response = execute()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            checkNotNull(response.body())
        } else {
            throw HttpException(response)
        }
    }
```

[Full solution code sample](https://github.com/p-fischer/coroutines-retrofit-limitparallism/tree/solution-sync-retrofit-calls)